# OpenCL CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE not consistent

Tags: memory, opencl, constants

I am trying to understand the value of CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE, specifically for a RX Vega 56 GPU. My own program queries and outputs the following:

```
CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE           : 4244635648
```

Moreover, using clinfo:

```
% clinfo | grep constant
Max constant buffer size                        4244635648 (3.953GiB)
Max number of constant args                     8
```

I would expect something like 65536, but getting almost 4 GB for the constant buffer size is too large. Could someone explain me what is going on? I was wondering that this could be a driver problem ...

I saw other people getting large values for such parameter too. See [here](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/216).

Comment: "getting almost 4 GB for the constant buffer size is too large" - why?

Answer (score 0):

GPU has  VideoMemory also called VRAM. And its all can be used as Constant Memory.